# how to get the rssi value for a bluetooth low energy device ?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

I am new with android programming and trying to get rssi value form a BLE device for distance measurements.i can scan and get the name and mac address of the device but i've tried codes to get the rssi but can't get useful result,also i use the sample on the android developer site.
can someone give me the right code to do so??

Comment: can you please share the working code. Please. thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Two solution for this.There is different approach one can have for 4.0 and 5.0 devices to search/scan BLE devices. You did not mentioned which one you are using, hence adding both the solution below.

1) for Android 4.4 + till 5.0, you have to start LE scanning via `BluetoothAdapter's` `startLEScan` method, which gives you below callback with RSSI value. see signature of method.

```
onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord)
```

// second param above is RSSI value.

2) For android 5.0+ devices you have to start scanning by BluetoothLeScanner class's startScan method, like below

```
getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan
```

which has callback onScanResult to notify for new scanned device, you can use below code to get rssi.

```
public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
final int rssi = result.getRssi(); //RSSI value
```

Comment: i am using android 4.3 , i used the first solution and it work probably. thank you !

Comment: @alaa, RSSI comes in - value, from -100 to 0.
if it works for you, you can accept the answer.

Comment: @AAnkit can you please share a working code? Thank you.