# How to Find strength of signals obtained from a BLE device in an Android app ?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, signal-strength

I am writing code for indoor navigation system. For tracking user position i am using Bluetooth low energy device. I am going to find user position based on strength he receive from these devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally rssi is the last byte you would receive when you analyze the raw data

for android hope this link works

[how to get the rssi value for a bluetooth low energy device ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365737/how-to-get-the-rssi-value-for-a-bluetooth-low-energy-device)

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is about how to get the rssi dynamically when  ble-low-energy device was connected.
So Maybe It's not the answer getting the RSSI from the scanning callback.

Is it possible getting the rssi value when ble-low-energy device is connected by other device?

Comment: Is this really an answer?

Comment: such as the case, I connected a BLE device, and want to update it's rssi value.